# Templatize functionpointer with default argument

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates, pointers

I want to templatize that code below:

```
void attachHelpfunctionPointer(void (* functionPointer)(int),  int test=0);
void (* helpFunctionPointer)(int);

void attachHelpfunctionPointer(void (* functionPointer)(int), int test) {
    helpFunctionPointer = functionPointer;   //pass the address
}
```

and then somewhere later in the code call it:

```
attachHelpfunctionPointer(testFunctionXY, testValue);  //attach new function with argument
helpFunctionPointer (test);   //pass the argument
```

how can I replace the type "`int`" by a template of type "`T`"?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work..

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
  std::function<void(T)> f_;
  void setFunc(std::function<void(T)> f, T def = {}) {
    // save
    f_ = [=](T p) {
      // pseudo code follows:
      // if not p
        f(def);
      // else
        f(p);
    };
  }

  void callFunc(T param) {
    f_(param);
  }
}
```

If you can't modify the approach (i.e. need to use a free function like you are doing to set it to some arbitrary object) then you will need to use some type such as `boost::any` (or `std::any` if you have C++17) for the parameter and in your function test it.. so the signature becomes `std::function<void(std::any)>`

EDIT: missed the default parameter criteria, so modified the save function a little bit.

Comment: Uff, that looks complicated, I don't even know what: "[=]" means. But Im gonna try that tomorrow, thanks

Comment: It's a lambda and whatever is in the square brackets `[]` is captured, two ways to capture, by value (copy) `=`, or by reference, the latter is a headache as you have to guarantee lifetime, and given this is just a default value, copy is easiest.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a code similar to your example, but templatized, using template variables.

Unfortunately they are available only starting from C++14.

By example

```
template <typename T>
void (* helpFunctionPointer)(T) = nullptr;

template <typename T>
void attachHelpfunctionPointer (void (*fP)(T), T test)
 { helpFunctionPointer<T> = fP; }
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void (* helpFunctionPointer)(T) = nullptr;

template <typename T>
void attachHelpfunctionPointer (void (*fP)(T), T test)
 { helpFunctionPointer<T> = fP; }

void foo (int)
 { std::cout << "foo (int function)" << std::endl; }

void bar (long)
 { std::cout << "bar (long function)" << std::endl; }

int main()
 {
   attachHelpfunctionPointer(foo, 0);
   attachHelpfunctionPointer(bar, 0L);

   helpFunctionPointer<int>(1);
   helpFunctionPointer<long>(1L);
 }
```

For C++11 the best I can imagine is wrap the function pointer in a template `struct` or `class` or something similar (see the Nim's answer, by example).

An iper-simplified example can be based on

```
template <typename T>
struct funcPtr
 { void (*fp)(T) = nullptr; };
```

The following is a full working (C++11) example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct funcPtr
 { void (*fp)(T) = nullptr; };

void foo (int)
 { std::cout << "foo (int function)" << std::endl; }

void bar (long)
 { std::cout << "bar (long function)" << std::endl; }

int main()
 {
   funcPtr<int>  fpi { foo };
   funcPtr<long> fpl { bar };

   fpi.fp(1);
   fpl.fp(1L);
 }
```

Comment: Unluckily I have C++11 (Arduino), but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Hydra - added a iper-simplified C++11 solution (but the Nim's one, based on `std::function` maybe is better)